# Rails 4 humanizer gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, captcha

I am trying to use humanizer gem on rails 4.0

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Humanizer
  require_human_on :create
end
```

and getting the following error.

```
uninitialized constant MyModel::Humanizer
```

Answer (score 2):

Was having the same issue.

Restarting the server should take care of it.